# object ml is not a member of package org.apache.spark

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to take my first steps in Mllib. My library dependencies are:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.2"
```

but I still get:

```
Error:(4, 27) object ml is not a member of package org.apache.spark
  import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression
```

Comment: For your information: I've deleted last sentence, as it's Off Topic on SO. Better to not risk closing ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've included dependency to Spark Core, you should also add Spark MLLib:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.2.0"
```

Or simpler:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.2.0"
```

Comment: That gives me the error: `Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-mllib_2.12 /2.2.0[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-mllib_2.12;2.2.0: not found`

Comment: @user1761806 Change your Scala version to 2.11. Spark does not support Scala 2.11 yet

Comment: Thanks had to change it specifically to 2.11.7 for it to be work but seems to have fixed that issue now. This is the sort of information that should be in the dependencies section of https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html